# Proper Azure AD Authentication flow for PWA - Progressive Web Apps

Tags: azure-active-directory, progressive-web-apps

Which Azure AD authentication flow is suitable for Progressive Web Apps (PWAs)?
Is the Implicit flow the only way?

Answer (score 0):

If your Progressive Web App is developed only as a static single page website i.e., without any server-side code (like C#, python..) then you have below options

1. The [implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow).
2. [Authorization Code Flow with Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636)

​
If you have server-side(backend) code running for the dinamic website then,
​

​

1. [OAuth 2 authorization code grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) is an option that will be more
   secure than implicit flow.
2. You can also use OAuth 2 [on-behalf-of authentication flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) as another
   option.This flow is used when an application invokes a service or
   web API, which in turn needs to call another service or web API.The
   idea is to propagate the delegated user identity and permissions
   through the request chain.

​
please refer [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows) for more information.
​
​